# Sticky footer - can it be moved?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, less

I have a sticky footer - nothing special but here's the code:

```
#fixed-footer
{
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:@z-fixed; (less)
}
```

All works fine, but I now have a slide in side menu like the one on facebook and many other mobile sites.

Again, nothing special - triggered by adding the class"right-menu":

```
#viewport
{
  left:0;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}

#nav
{
    .InnerShadow(-1.5rem, 0, 1.5rem -0.75rem, 0.25);
    background-color:@navy;
    height:100%;
    left:-70%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:70%;
    z-index:@z-off-canvas;
}

.right-menu #viewport
{
    left:70%;
}
```

However, the fixed footer remains in place when the menu - I can add a margin to the real footer to avoid any collision but what I'd like to do, if possible, is move the fixed footer when the rest of the page is shifted right.

Any ideas, if or how this can be done?

Comment: Does `.right-menu #fixed-footer { left:70%; }` not work?

Comment: Haha, I guess I've had too much time off - thanks for pointing out the obvious Josh.

Comment: Hey Josh, can you add that as an answer below so dotnetnoob can mark this question as answered?